# Multiprocessing.Pool not speeding up overall computation

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, grid-search, hyperparameters

I try to do a hyperparameters search for a Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithm using Pytorch.

I have a list of hyperparameters `hyperparams_list` to try and a function `test_hyperparams()` that creates and test my RL model corresponding to the given `hyperparams`.
I have a 16 cores machine and a GPU so I would like to do this using multiprocessing and Cuda.
This is what I tried to do so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_hyperparams(hyperparams):
    # initialize RL model with hyperparams as input
    # train RL algo while logging results

hyperparams_list = [hyperparams0, ...,hyperparamsN]
with Pool(num_cores) as p:
    infos = p.map(test_hyperparams, hyperparams_list)
```

Running this code, I noticed that it actually did not speed up my hyperparameters search, since each training was taking 16 times longer than before.

Yet, by typing the commands `top` and `nvidia-smi` in the terminal, I could see that each of the 16 processes was taking the expected amount of GPU memory and was running on multiple cores.

Comment: if you have only 1 GPU then you can only train 1 model at a time ... unless your models are underutilizing the GPU.

Comment: Yes they are ! Each model uses about 800MiB (it's a low data regime) and my GPU has about 11000MiB (I actually run 10 processes)

Comment: For underutilizing, I think @AhmedAEK means `GPU-Util` rate instead of memory usage. You can check it with `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: Even if you can fit 10 models in the GPU, they can compete with each other if the GPU-Util is more than 10% for each program alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed each program was using 40% GPU-Util. However I should be able to train 2 models twice as fast since 2 models use "only" 80%. Yet, when I run it, each process still takes 2 times longer...